# Using digital crown on Apple Watch to change size text (watchOS 2)

Tags: apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm got an issue with Apple Watch & watchOS 2.
I have a string like: `Hello World`, now I want whenever I'm swivel the Digital Crown the size of my string will be increase. I'm just start working with Apple Watch for 3 days & don't understand all about it. Please help me guys.

Comment: The text size must be based on the size setting in the Settings app. It is better to set the size relative on the main settings in the Apple Watch, which can be completely different between users. Also there are exception apps such as QuranMajeed which you must set the text size within the app itself, but it is better to follow Apple Human Interface Guidelines and set the texts relative to the main settings.